# Have any one compare eigen function on opencv & eigen?

Tags: opencv, eigen

I need to compute the eigenvalue and eigenvector with C++ and retrieve the eigenvector with the smallest eigenvalue.

So I found two libraries(OpenCV & Eigen) that provided the function to compute eigen, and
want to compare their speed. As far as I know Eigen is specialized in numerical and linear algebra, but after the experiment eigen is slower than OpenCV. Does anyone know why? Is my code not efficient?

Eigen snippet:

```
Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXd> es(h_cov);
Eigen::VectorXd eigen_value = es.eigenvalues().real();
Eigen::MatrixXd eigen_vec = es.eigenvectors().real();
int min_index = -1;
eigen_values.minCoeff(&min_index);
Eigen::Vector3d smallest_eigen_vec = eigen_vec.col(min_index);
```

OpenCV snippet:

```
cv::Mat33d eigen_vec;
cv::Matx31d eigen_val;
cv::eigen(h_conv, eigen_val, eigen_vec);
cv::Matx31d smallest_eigen_vec = eigen_vec.row(2).t();
```

Comment: Do you know at compile-time that your matrix is 3x3? In that case use `Matrix3d`/`Vector3d` in Eigen as well. Also, in case you know that your matrix is symmetric (e.g., if you have a _cov_ariance matrix), use the `SelfAdjointEigenSolver` in Eigen.

Comment: See [eigen performance](http://www.eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Optimization) by the eigen developers.  First make sure you have optimizations turned on and certainly follow chtz's advice of fixed size matrices for small matrices.